# jQuery load fragment for several purposes once

Tags: ajax, jquery, load

I am loading options for few select lists using load and fragment.

This is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#select1").load("ts.xml #select1", 
                 function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                   if (textStatus == "success") {
                        alert("Loaded select 1");

                   }  

        $("#select2").load("ts.xml #select2", 
                 function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                   if (textStatus == "success") {
                        alert("Loaded select 2");

                   }     
    });
```

And my html looks like this:

```
<li id="select1" class="left"></li>
<li id="select2" class="left"></li>
```

where the **ts.xml** looks like this:

```
<select id="select1">
<option>Lorem</option>
<option>Ipsum</option>
<option>Lorem Ipsum</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
<option>Lorem</option>
<option>Ipsum</option>
<option>Lorem Ipsum</option>
</select>
```

**How can I load the ts.xml once and keep retrieving fragment out of it?** Note that every time I retrieve a fragment I want to alert a success not on ts.xml load.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Load once, cache, then use the cached version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var response;
    $("#select1").load("ts.xml #select1", 
        function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
           if (textStatus == "success") {
                response = responseText; // this will be your xml response
                // now you can use 'response' anywhere inside the doc.ready function
           }
        });    
});
```

Comment: Can you please show me how can I recall for the select2 with the 'response' as the xml cache? I understood the concept of it but I don't know how to make it, therefore I asked the question. Thanks alot

Comment: @adeneo's answer would be the way to do it. If you convert `response` into a jQuery object ( response = $(responseText) ), then you can use jQuery methods to parse through it. So, when you need to populate #select2, you just grab the `response` variable and manipulate it so.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would probably go back to the basic $.ajax function and do something like this.

```
var xmlData;

function getXML() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "ts.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    error: function() {
    $("#mydiv").append("<p>File Not Found!</p><br />");
    },
    success: function(xml){
        xmlData = $(xml);
    }
});
```

Now you can search the data anywhere, atleast I think so, not tested but can't see why not?

```
var Searchvalue = "Lorem";

xmlData.find("select1").find("option:contains('" + Searchvalue + "')").each(function(){
        // do something
        });
```